# Why did Agda give up cumulative universes?

Tags: agda, universe-polymorphism, cumulativity

In Ulf Norell's PhD thesis, which is considered the standard reference of the Agda 2 language, the universes are cumulative, say, `Set i` is not just an instance of `Set (suc i)`, but also a subtype of it.

However, in the implementation of Agda, this is not true. We only have the "instance of" relation, not the subtype relation, until recently (`--cumulativity`).

IMO, it is good to have more flexibility, but why would Agda developers delete this in the beginning? What inconveniences or problems did cumulative universes bring to us?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One reason (not particularly specific to Agda) might be that eta reduction is not compatible with cumulativity.

With cumulativity (that is $Set_0 \leq Set_1$), and given
\begin{align*}
f &:= \lambda X.(\lambda Y.Y)X &: Set_0\to Set_1\\
f_\eta &:= \lambda Y.Y &: Set_1\to Set_1\\
f_\beta &:= \lambda X.X &: Set_0\to Set_0
\end{align*}
we would have (and we can prove, say, in Coq)
$$ f \equiv_\eta f_\eta\qquad\text{ and }\qquad f\equiv_\beta f_\beta$$
which are well-typed because
$$(Set_1\to Set_1) \leq (Set_0\to Set_1)\quad\text{ and }\quad(Set_0 \to Set_0) \leq (Set_0\to Set_1) ,$$
but we have the awkward situation that $f_\eta$ is not comparable to $f_\beta$.

---

So while Coq has cumulativity but does not eta-reduce (it does eta-convert however), Agda supports eta-reduction (please correct me if this is wrong) but does not support cumulativity.

Comment: Nice thank you very much

Comment: I don't agree with your first displayed $\eta$-equivalence.  $\eta$-conversion is fundamentally a typed notion; it can't equate your LHS of type $\rm Set_0 \to Set_0$ with your RHS of type $\rm Set_1 \to Set_1$.  Also I don't know what you mean by "Coq does not eta-reduce"; since quite some time ago Coq does have definitional $\eta$-conversion.

Comment: @MikeShulman The type of the LHS is actually $Set_0\to Set_1$ (I verified with Check in Coq), which is a supertype of $Set_1\to Set_1$, so this is well typed. Similarly, $Set_0\to Set_1$ is a subtype of $Set_0\to Set_0$. When I try this in Coq, Coq is happy with stating the first two equalities, (the first requires extensionality), but the third produces a universe inconsistency.

Comment: @MikeShulman So this confused me for a while, but the distinction between conversion and reduction in Coq is that it can tell when two convertible terms are convertible, but it cannot reduce terms because subtyping does not guarantee that their types are convertible.

Comment: You example relies on having annotated abstractions, and indeed it is part of the reasons why having η in the reduction is problematic in Coq. But Agda’s abstractions are unannotated, so the issue should disappear…

Comment: But @MikeShulman if by "η-conversion is fundamentally a typed notion" you mean you have to use types in your conversion algorithm, this is false: Coq’s conversion check does not maintain any types.

Comment: Doesn't this argument apply to subtyping in general? Current Agda has a limited amount of subtyping, so this can't be a fatal issue.

Comment: This seems just another example of "eta-reduction is broken (even without cumulativity), use (type-directed) eta-expansion", which I think is what Agda uses.

Comment: In fact, Agda does have eta-reduction (at least for records!), but it's still unsound: https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2732.