# Is eta-equality provable in Coq?

Tags: coq, functional-extensionality, eta-conversion

Trying to answer [another question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/239/why-did-agda-give-up-cumulative-universes/243#243), I can't help second guessing myself about whether eta equality is provable in Coq. In particular, can one prove

```
Theorem eta : forall (A : Type) (f : A -> A), (fun x => f x) = f?
```

Does this require functional extensionality?

---

*Edit*: I already accepted an answer, but a better (followup) question would be, if Coq supports eta-conversion, why does `Eval compute in (fun x => f x).` not reduce to `f`?

Comment: It should be noted that even if we have reduction rules related to eta-equality, we would usually do *expansion* instead of contraction, because it leads to better theoretic properties.

Comment: @GuyCoder it should probably be a synonym

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this is provable—indeed, it is provable by `reflexivity`. This is because [Coq has eta-equality of functions built into its notion of definitional equality](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/conversion.html#expansion). Definitional equality also has a congruence rule for lambdas, which does look kind of like function extensionality, but which exists at the *judgmental* level, and is about *definitional* equality rather than propositional equality. This does not allow us to prove function extensionality, because the premise in function extensionality is a propositional equality and not a definitional one. In the presence of an equality reflection rule, this *would* furnish a proof of function extensionality, which is why type systems with equality reflection, eta for functions, and defeq congruence for lambdas validate function extensionality.

Answer (score 10):

As for your follow-up question: Coq implements η-conversion, but not η-reduction/expansion, because η really is treated at the level of the conversion test and not at that of reduction (which is a sub-routine thereof). Concretely, the conversion test works roughly as follows when comparing `t` and `u`:

1. reduce `t` and `u` to weak head normal forms (using a bunch of reduction rules including β but *not* η)
2. if one of the reducts is a neutral `n` and the other is an abstraction `fun x : A => t`, recursively compare `n x` and `t` (this corresponds to η-expanding the neutral followed by a congruence rule for abstraction)

The reasons to do things like this are a bit tricky, but the bottom line is that implementing η inside reduction (be it as expansion or reduction) would either break good properties or simply be unfeasable in current Coq.

I did a talk about this at WITS a few weeks ago, the video does not seem to be up on Youtube yet (it should be there at some point) but the slides and abstract are [on my page](https://www.meven.ac/category/talks.html).