# Equality of two functions

Tags: lean3, equality

I am wondering about definition of functions in Lean and proving equality (in some sense to be defined) of two functions.

**Note:** I have consulted the answer to the following related question but it does not answer my doubts: [Definitional vs propositional equality](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/1837/2122).

Concretely, I am considering the following:

```
variables {X : Type}

def id1 (x : X) : X :=
x

def id2 : X → X := 
λ x, x
```

The commands `print id1` and `print id2` then return

```
def id1 : Π {X : Type}, X → X :=
λ {X : Type} (x : X), x
```

and

```
def id2 : Π {X : Type}, X → X :=
λ {X : Type} (x : X), x
```

My first question then is:

> Does this mean that `id1` and `id2` are *definitionally equal*?

What I can do is prove

```
example : ∀ x : X, id1 x = id2 x := by {intro x, refl}
```

which suggests that `id1` and `id2` are indeed definitionally equal (because, as I understand, `refl` will only work on definitionally equal terms).

However, even if the above is correct, I am puzzled by the following: the command `#check id1 = id2`returns `id1 = id2 : Prop` but if I try

```
example : id1 = id2 := by {sorry}
```

I get a

> don't know how to synthetize placeholder 
>  context: 
>  ⊢ Type

and a

> tactic failed, result contains meta-variables

so I guess that the statement `id1 = id2` does not quite make sense. Hence my second question:

> Is it possible to give meaning to the statement `id1 = id2` and prove it?

**Note:** I believe this could be related to [$\eta$-equivalence](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/expressions.html) of terms, but I do really understand what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, since you have implicit arguments in your functions, Lean thinks you have left out the argument (that's what implicit means!), so it interprets your statement as

```
id1 {X = ??} = id2 {X = ??}
```

(This is not Lean syntax, it is just to demonstrate the problem.)
And Lean then starts to figure out what the question marks should be. But of course it would fail, because there is absolutely no information that tells Lean what those are.

---

The above is likely not your real question, so what if we give the type `X` for Lean? We can do this by using `@id1 X`. The `@` tells Lean to make all arguments explicit so you can provide them one by one. Let's check:

```
example : @id1 X = @id2 X := by refl
```

It passes! So `id1` and `id2` are indeed definitionally equal. Note that this is *not* what we conventionally call "function extensionality". This is called $\eta$-equality, it states that

> If the body of two functions are definitionally equal, then they are definitionally equal.

What the Lean community calls "functional extensionality" states that

> If for every $x$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are propositionally equal, then $f$ and $g$ are propositionally equal.

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but technically `@id1 X = @id2 X := by refl` only checks that _once applied at a given type `X`_, `id1` and `id2` are equal. But I guess that also `@id1 = @id2 := by refl` type-checks, which is really meaning that without giving them any further arguments, the two functions are (definitionally) equal. Although, because Lean's definitional equality contains η-equality, these two statement are equivalent (but this is a feature!).

Comment: Thanks also for the clarification about functional extensionality, I have removed the tag.

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand You're right, I figured that the OP is asking about the case with `X` a fixed constant throughout the question. But that's a good addition.

Comment: Another nitpick, but η-equality is more commonly understood as the rule $t \equiv (\lambda x.\, t\ x)$. The rule you refer to is traditionally called the ξ-rule, or just congruence for abstraction. You can have a system with ξ but without η, that was e.g. the case in the old versions of Coq.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the $\xi$-rule: does it mean that `f = g` implies that `∀ x, f x = g x`? That's what I inferred from [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28663), but I'm not sure I'm getting this right.