# Why is cumulativity not a given in proof assistants?

Tags: cumulativity

It seems to me that there are no real reasons to not like cumulativity (the example given [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/239/why-did-agda-give-up-cumulative-universes) seems to not be too relevant, according to the comments), and yet most proof assistants (apart from Coq?) don't have cumulativity. Why is this so? This seems a very nice property mathematically, and is akin to how most people would think of universes intuitively.

Comment: It breaks unique typing. In fact, having used Agda for a while, I don't see any non-marginal benefit it can give, unless you are deliberately trying to stretch the proof assistant. But good question (+1).

Comment: In Lean, if you're using category theory then you might find that you want several things all to be in the same universe. If you're trying to write universe-agnostic code then this might mean that you want a copy of the integers or the reals in your universe. Lean's `int` and `real` live in `Type := Type 0`, the bottom universe. If I want to copy them over to another universe I have to `ulift` them and right now there's a bunch of API which is missing on the lifted copies (e.g. the order structure), although some API does lift (e.g. the ring structure). Of course this is just missing API...

Comment: @KevinBuzzard: What precisely are you pointing out? That not having cummulativity in Lean is suboptimal because of the lifting stuff?

Comment: Right now it's suboptimal because we have to API ourselves around lack of universe cumulativity and nobody got around to doing it yet.

Comment: Another option is to define types like `int` to be polymorphic, with a specified copy in every universe.

Comment: @Trebor You lose unique typing, but if the situation is nice enough (eg Coq’s type theory) you still get principal typing – there exists a unique *minimal* type (for cumulativity), up to conversion –, and this is enough in quite a few situation imho.

Answer (score 19):

The short answer is that cummulativity is just one possible design choice which does not fit all purposes.

The slightly longer answer is that baking commulativity into type theory is a very dramatic design choice that complicates the typing rules, equality and conversion, universe management, and the semantics.

The real question is not whether we should have cummulativity but rather how to organize universes so that the user can control them when they wish or must do so, and at the same time the proof assistant can handle them by itself in a reasonable way. It is not clear (to me) that cummulativity is the best way to approach the problem. There are other options, such as implicit coercions, explicit coercions (also known as "lifting"), univere polymorphism, etc.

There is also a wider issue, namely that from a foundational point of view there seems little reason to fix a specific hierachy of universes (such as a linearly ordered sequence of universes indexed by natural numbers). You may call me a logician but I really dislike arbitrary choices in foundations of mathematics.

Comment: To be fair, the reason that this is bothering me currently is that in Lean, explicit tyles like `nat/rat` are in `Type`, as opposed to `Type u`. So making things more polymorphic would fix this sort of issue. What sort of complications does it cause on the typing rules? Is this the sort of thing that's mentioned on the linked question?

Comment: I found out from Mario Carneiro on the Lean Zulip that "complication" further implies that it's actually still an open problem whether Coq's type theory is consistent (and similarly for a cumulative Lean). The extent of this complication wasn't clear to me

Comment: @ItsNotALie There is actually nothing conceptual preventing Lean types like `nat`/``rat` from being universe polymorphic (and thus allowing one to avoid `ulift` or the like. There are a few places where the introduction of universe metavariables can through off otherwise straightforward type inference, but mostly it is just convention for things to be in `Type` when they can be rather than defining them in `Type u`. There are arguments for transitioning to the later, but that would likely need some heavy discussion by the community.

Comment: I am fairly sure that Coq's type theory (or at least a great deal of it) has an interpretation in set theory with some number of inaccessible cardinals. Can you point me to the Zulip thread where the claim is made, perhaps there's some further information there that is not getting across.

Comment: As for putting `nat` into `Type u` for all `u` – that breaks the principle of *uniqueness of typing*: if `a : A` and `a : B` then `A ≡ B`. Uniqueness of typing is good to have. For if not, then you might think it is a type error to write `a ≡ a` because lhs and rhs have different types (and that's just the tip of the iceberg). Without uniqueness of typing you have to come up with some other way of comparing types, such as a subtyping relation, and this drags in *a great deal* of complications, see ice1000 answer below.

Comment: By the way, if you are suggesting that there be one copy `nat u` (with `u` implicit and hidden from the user) for each level `u`, that would restore uniqueness of typing, but who wants to have infinitely many copies of natural numbers running arround, all seemingly named `nat`?

Comment: What would it mean to avoid an arbitrary foundational choice about the organization of universes? Does that just mean imposing as little structure on universe levels as possible? ([i.e. a semilattice with successor](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/750/788)?)

Comment: Ideally, universes should be a user-definable feature, or at least something that an advanced user would imlpement. It need not be a semilattice.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that? Induction-induction or logical frameworks come to mind but I have a feeling that's not what you mean. (If the answer is elaborate, perhaps I could ask an site-level question about it?)

Comment: @AndrejBauer here's a link to the relevant archive: https://leanprover-community.github.io/archive/stream/270676-lean4/topic/universes.html#272684374

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Thank you. All I see there is an unsubstantiated claim in quotes. Perhaps there are some Coq developers lurking here who can comment on this business of "consistency [of Coq] is widely believed but an open question". At least a very large chunk of Coq obviously has a set-theoretic model, including cummulative universes. It ought to be at least as consistent as ZFC + countably many inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: @JamesMartin: Universes are by no means necessary in a proof assistant. They are rather one possible solution that gets implemented over and over, and which seems to cover most needs. All I am saying is that baking in a solution just because the previous proof assistant baked in the solution is not necessarily the way of progress. Of course, we learn a great deal with every generation of proof assistants, and we *should* reuse good solutions. But we should also be on the lookout for implicit assumptions about the design. I feel that sometimes universes are taken for granted.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'll open up a question, I guess asking about the general status of consistency of the metatheory of proof assistants in general.

Comment: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/936/what-is-known-about-the-consistency-of-proof-assistant-metatheories

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Here's a proof of consistenct of Coq's Calculus of Constructions: https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0123 This could be posted on the relevant Lean chat.

Answer (score 10):

The biggest problem in my head is that cumulativity opens the door of subtyping in type theory, which, IMO, a potential calamity to type theory. If you elaborate cumulativity to non-cumulativity + lifting, then it's probably fine, but let me say something about the subtyping-based approach.

Once you have subtyping, you'll start thinking about covariance and contravariance, which brings a lot more things to the type theory. Also, subtyping itself distinguishes two notions: consider $(a:A)\in\Gamma$, then "the type of $a$" and "$A$" are no longer the same under the context $\Gamma$. Instead, "the type of $a$" is a subtype of $A$, and when you want to, for example, apply $a$ to the identity function with the type argument an implicit argument, then probably you can't solve the metavariable because $A$ won't be the most accurate solution (I thank Pavel for sharing some ideas with me about this).

Apart from that, cumulativity generates more complex universe level equations, which are harder to solve.